# Get top position of dynamic element with no events involved

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Currently working on a project and got stuck. Have a lazy loading implemented on UL element and want to get its relative/absolute top position on load/fetch new elements.

Is there a possibility of getting those values not involving any mouse events (scrollstart, scroll, click, touchstart, touch)

Currently I am getting such values using:

```
$('#elem').position().top;
```

and always fetching new elements position().top changes, however console.log shows 'static' values which don't change accordingly.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

read up here

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an event to get the position of an element (other than that all JavaScript code in browsers runs in response to *some* kind of event, in the larger sense of the word). In your code where you need to know this, just use [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/):

```
var top = $("selector-for-the-element").offset().top;
```

Example:

```js
console.log("#three's top is " + $("#three").offset().top);
```

```html
<div>One</div>
<div>Two</div>
<div id="three">Three</div>
<div>One</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```